# bm800 mic no sound but static issue

Tags: sound

I've got a Floureon condenser mic and cant figure out how to get it to rec my audio all it does is rec static i do not have a power supply with it so that might be the issue please help thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up your mic input to provide "plugin power" (using the maximum in case you have several settings).  How to do that depends on your computer in question (assuming that you are using a mic input on a computer), or if you use an XLR connector on mixer or external soundcard, you'll need to switch on phantom power.

Since you have not bothered specifying what you are connecting your microphone to, the specifics how to do that cannot be answered.  Once you have that working, you'll have some signal and be back to already answered questions on this site on how to improve the signal-to-noise ratio on this microphone that may be powered by a wide variety of voltages.

Comment: so its just going into my motherboard i got it to pick up some sound but its only when i pretty much put the mic in my mouth and its very quite and mainly static